# can't add foreign key in mysql (through phpmyadmin)

Tags: phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

error: cannot add foreign key. check data type.

What is wrong with my data type?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

Cannot SET NULL to columns that can't be NULL